# How can I use a button within a listView such that when I click that button, I can get that selected item and run a query on it?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I basically have this shopping cart app and in my `listView` it displays me all the items such as the item's description, store, brand, price, and the image of it and under each item, there's an add to cart button. So when I click on this button for an item, I want to run a query and add that item to my existing database. I am using a button `onClickListener`, but how do I first get that specific item in my `listView` for which I clicked the button and then run the query on that item's info such as the description, brand, store, price, etc.? I haven't posted my code, but I just need to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Every time if you create a item layout you can use the index of the row as tag for your button.

Here is an example:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MYItem> implements View.OnClickListener {

    public MyListAdapter () { [...] }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, parent, false);
        }

        MYItem item = getItem(position);

        [...]

        View btn = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
        btn.setTag(position);

        return view;
    }

    // now you can get row index in this way:

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        Integer index = (Integer ) v.getTag();
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="addToCart?cartId=<%=product.getCartId()%>"><button type="button">Add to Cart</button></a>
```

1. Suppose `addToCart()` is your method.
2. Annotate your method as (If you are using spring framework)
   `@RequestMapping(value="addToCart",method=RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: <a href="yourmethod"><button type="button">Button_Name</button></a>

Comment: I'm actually not using the Spring framework, so basically this is what I want when I click on the button. First it'll give me a toast, which I already have and then it should call a method called addToCart(), which will perform a query essentially to add that item to the cart. But before I do that, I need to get that specific item in the listView, so how can I get that item and it's information such as the brand, store, price, etc.?

Comment: According to you, you have some items like brand,store,price etc. in your list view which is coming from some database table.And in your list view, there is button "Add to cart". You want that on clicking this button all items should hit method and run query. If right then

Comment: suppose "productId" is the primary key of the table from which brand,store,price is coming.Then productId with your method as

Comment: <a href="yourmethod?productId=<%=product.getProductId()%>"><button type="button>Button_Name</button></a>

Comment: Then get record by productId from previous table and insert into another table.

Comment: Well I was thinking that instead in the Button onClickListener that I have there's some way, I can get the position of that item in the listView for which the button is clicked, and then get that item and then get that item's brand, price, store, description, etc. and then run a query on it? How can I do it like that?